# creating a quiz where one word from a list is the answer to another, Translation game

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I am trying to create a translation game between dutch and english, and thus chose to create two different list where the english word and the dutch word are in the same index space. I have tried to make the english word a variable assigned to the `specialWord`. I then made it an integer. I then hopefully tried to use that integer as the index number to find the dutch word.

ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple error occurs.

The Code:

```
import random

eng = ("castle", "home", "man", "woman", "green")
dutch = ("kasteel", "huis", "man", "vrouw", "groen")

count = 0
correct = 0
userInput = ' '

def quiz():
    global count, correct, userInput
    while userInput != 'exit':
        specialWord = random.choice(eng)
        print('what is the dutch translaion for ' + specialWord + '?')
        index1 = eng.index(specialWord)
        index2 = int(index1)
        dutchWord = dutch.index(index2)
        print(index1)
        userInput = input('Answer: ').lower()
        if userInput == specialWord:
            correct += 1
            count += 1
            print("correct: " + str(correct) + "/" + str(count))
        else:
            correct += 0
            count += 1
            print("Incorrect: " + str(correct) + "/" + str(count))

quiz()
```

I tried to make it an integer as seen in the code, then I tried to google it but could not express properly what I needed to find.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected it for you. You can simply get the respective dutch value for the English word by calling the list and giving the index of the English word from the list. You don't have to cast it

```
import random

eng = ("castle", "home", "man", "woman", "green")
dutch = ("kasteel", "huis", "man", "vrouw", "groen")

count = 0
correct = 0
userInput = ' '

def quiz():
    global count, correct, userInput
    while userInput != 'exit':
        specialWord = random.choice(eng)
        print('what is the dutch translaion for ' + specialWord + '?')
        index1 = eng.index(specialWord)
        #index2 = int(index1) ### you don't need this
        dutchWord = dutch[index1] ### directly use the index1 which you got above
        print(index1)
        userInput = input('Answer: ').lower()
        if userInput == dutchWord:  ## check here ive changed this
            correct += 1
            count += 1
            print("correct: " + str(correct) + "/" + str(count))
        else:
            correct += 0
            count += 1
            print("Incorrect: " + str(correct) + "/" + str(count))

quiz()
```

Also when comparing the value from the user input, you need to compare it with the dutch word and not the English word